# How to get url path

Tags: php, url

How to get the complete URL path which user uses to visit my website.
I made an affiliate marketing program in my website so I gave each and every single business manager a unique URL each time my website is visited I want to get the full URL of the visitor

Answer (score 0):

I think you want is to get referrer link that uses to visit your website

```
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

you can read manual [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)